# copy paste of an infopath repeating table line resets a numerical field to zero

Tags: forms, copy-paste, repeat, infopath

Got infopath form with a repeating table that has 6 columns. some text, some numbers, some dates. 
plus there is a SUM TOTAL field that sums up one of the numbers columns.

everything is good except if we cut and paste a line of the repeating table (within the same form or to another instance of the same form - another XML on SharePoint ) the number field changes to ZERO and we have to remember what it was before and type it down again into form(everything else is copied correctly).

can't figure it out.

barely even a beginner in infopath filler/designer. I clicked around the properties of the table and fields. there are some rules but they're about the 2 date fields so I'm at lost.

the fact that whoever made this form probably reformed some other form to make it work doesn't help as there are many hidden fields (as I'm looking at it at infopath designer) we don't use or need so its confusing.

I'm at loss as to what can possibly reset a numerical field in the repeating table when you copy and paste that entire line. every other field gets pasted correctly other than that one. it changes from whatever number (anything from 1 to 11000) that was there before to 0 - zero.

I thought it maybe got something to do with the sum total function field that sums up all that column and deleted it just to see if it changes anything but it didn't.

it can't be null/empty. could it be the reason? can't find how to change it though.

I can upload the xsn to somewhere I guess  -if needed

edit: can you see this ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/10vaitN0CFuEgwvuY3cxiArRVLw2AizA3/view?usp=drivesdk

edit2: what i'm trying to do and cant is fill the middle (of7) columns in the repeating table with a number. any number. then copy the entire row to a new added one in the same form , or move it, or cut (ctrl+x) it  (the whole row) to another instance of this form (as xml in sharepoint) , while KEEPING the number value. at the moment  - whatever i do, copypaste or cut paste, the value of that field changes to 0.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: i have so you may want to be more specific. or not.

Comment: Ok, cool, that's a good start. Does your question contain everything someone else needs to reproduce the problem, and nothing too much more, i.e., a [mcve]? I don't see any code or other ways to reproduce your problem. It's a bit like calling the vet and asking what's wrong with your dog without showing the dog to the vet.

Comment: oh ok. uploaded the xsn file - hopefully its viewable.